# How to block sudo commands based on arguments

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, sudoers

I have a file with root permissions like this

```
[root@testbox ~]# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 113 Feb 21 21:29 /etc/resolv.conf
```

I have enabled passwordless sudo for my user using /etc/sudoer

```
%mayur ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I want some way where if I try to edit this particular file I get blocked.
for eg .. I want to block these commands based on THE FILE NAME

```
$ echo 123 | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf  ## SHOULD GET BLOCKED
$ touch newfile | echo 123 > newfile | sudo cp newfile /etc/resolv.conf  ## SHOULD GET BLOCKED
```

My Efforts:

```
%mayur ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL,!/* /etc/resolv.conf
```

- This did not help at all.
- I also checked sudoers man page but it
  seems regex support isnt that great.

Any things that works will help. Thanks.

**EDIT: I want to be able to apply the solutions accross multiple servers with multiple users having sudo access**

Comment: Do not do this.  You will **never** find all the holes in the naive, amateurish attempts that will result, and will only achieve an **illusion of security** that is far more dangerous than having everyone fully aware of the risks of acting as the superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A EXCLUDE
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    EXCLUDE[$FILE]=.
done < /etc/sudoers.exclude-list
for ARG in "$@"; do
    TARGET=$(exec /usr/bin/readlink -m -- "$ARG")
    [[ -n $TARGET && -n ${EXCLUDE[$FILE]} ]] && {
        echo "sudo: Sorry, target is not allowed: $TARGET"
        exit 1
    }
done
exec /path/to/real/sudo-in-secured-location "$@"
```

Where `/etc/sudoers.exclude-list` is a line-based list of absolute real file paths. Entries must not contain extra spaces and list must not be in DOS format.

This script must have same ownership and permissions as the real sudo.

Comment: Thanks, this could be the basis for bash input validation/filter.

Comment: @MayurRokade I actually meant that it would replace `/usr/bin/sudo` in which `/usr/bin/sudo` would be moved somewhere inaccessible to users but still accessible by the script. You really have to know what you're doing to do this though.

Comment: I got what you are trying to say, this would be like  

`USER-COMMANDS -> SUDO_WRAPPER -> SUDOERS_EXCLUDE_LIST -> REAL_SUDO`  

Rather than regular  
`USER-COMMANDS -> REAL_SUDO`

Comment: No, this is horribly unwise as it is easily defeated by running something else first.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Any credible flaw you see in it? Explicit example that it could be defeated? And take note of the permission `rxs--x--x`.

Comment: Sure, run a shell.  Or any allowed command which has been modified to provide one.  The scope of what you have to audit expands quickly beyond reason.  The question does not have an answer within normal unix.

Comment: I'm asking how it could be defeated not the added difficulty of possible auditing when needed. What do you exactly mean about `any allowed command which has been modified to provide one`? Can you be more apparent or specific with what you mean? It's tagged as `linux` by the way and I find it likely to be for `linux`. And I hope you're not being concerned now about the scope of the question in SO. Can you provide any example that could affect the script I posted?

Comment: @konsolebox I suppose Chris meant any command (out of many!) that lets you run external commands; try eg ":!sh" in vi...

Comment: @loreb So what about running `sh`?

Comment: @konsolebox once you're running sh as root you can use it to run **anything**, including eg editing resolv.conf :)

Comment: @loreb The title was `how to block sudo commands based on arguments`.

Comment: @konsolebox Yep, and imho that's the point - once you allow everything, trying to limit damage is a battle you can only lose (finally found what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504272/which-is-better-white-list-or-black-list-security-or-both).

Comment: I actually thought you're saying that my script could be fooled in some way or could give security leak. It's pretty obvious that anyone can run a shell with sudo if allowed. However, if that's your concern, I believe it should be the OP's thread in which you should say those suggestions. My script works the way it should as per OP's requirement. It could also be improved to become a better filter.

Comment: @konsolebox doh! must be the summer heat...