# Spring Security & Spring MVC: how to implement 'Restrictions' instead of 'Permissions'?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my production environment all users have USER role and can access all REST endpoints.

By default, users may call any REST endpoints. But I need to implement a 2-level ban system to penalise users who break rules, namely, forbid access to 3 REST endpoints at level 1, and forbid access to ~50 endpoints at level 2.

AS far as I see, I need to implement specific roles DISABLE_X and DISABLE_Y and protect target endpoints with `@PreAuthorize` annotations, so if user `hasRole()` `DISABLE_COMMENTS` or `DISABLE_ALL` he CANNOT access these endpoints:

```
@PreAuthorize(!hasRole(DISABLE_COMMENTS))
public ModelAndView postComment(...) {...}
```

Is it a correct way in terms of Spring Security? What are the drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Sorry for a typo in the caption

Comment: I think the following documentation shows the best way to implement the `@PreAuthorize` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access       https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/

Comment: And if you need some orientation about white-list and black-list  approaches there  is a good article here https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/01/whitelisting_vs.html

Comment: Here's another article on white-list security VS black-list security : [Which is better, white list or black list security, or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504272/1429387)